# vim: how to replace submatches in matchlist()?

Tags: regex, vim

Is there a good way to replace submatches in `matchlist()` and modify the original line with it? I like to write a script which modifies all of the submatches in a **pattern** (which can be **anything what the user wants**),  in one step.

For **example** the original line is `some AfooBar` and the user like to change it to `some CfooDar`.

Thinking on the **universal solution, which works on any patter**:

```
let pattern = '\(A\)foo\(B\)'
let line    = 'some AfooBar'
let found   = matchlist( line, pattern )
```

The `found` contains `['AfooB', 'A', 'B', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`. Now i have to modify the `line` to `some CfooDar` so the best should be to reuse the array of matchlist() by modifying the numbers in it, then "compile" the line:

```
let found[1] = 'C'
let found[3] = 'D'
let line     = MATCHLIST_TO_STRING( found )
```

As i know it's not possible with the builtin functions, so i need to write one. The beginning of the line is not modified till the match, thus i can copy that part to the 'new_line':

```
let new_line = strpart( line, 0, match( line, pattern ) )
```

But at this point i don't know how to continue. I can append the modified `A` immediately, because the pattern starts with it (**in this example**, but the user can use any kind of pattern). But how can i find out the (offset) index of the `foo` and the `B`? In this example it's trivial, because there is no other `foo` and `B` in the line, but let see another example:

```
let line    = 'A A A A A'
let pattern = 'A \(A\) A \(A\)'
```

If i like to modify this to `A B A C A` then it's hard to detect the position of the submatches in the `line`.

One solution is to use submatches for the 'inner words' (like `foo` in the previous example), but it decreasing the number of useful submatches. For example:

```
let pattern  = '\(A\)\(foo\)\(B\)'
let line     = 'some AfooBar'
let found    = matchlist( line, pattern )
" Remove the full match, we need only the submatches.
call remove( found, 0 )
let found[0] = 'C'
let found[2] = 'D'
let new_line = strpart( line, 0, match( line, pattern ) ) . join( found, '')
```

In this case we used one additional submatch, but the `A \(A\) A \(A\) A` may become `\(A \)\(A\)\( A \)\(A\)\( A\)` and it's too lot.

So is there a good way to replace all of the submatches with a new value in one step?

Answer (score 0):

The entire question smells XY. What about asking about your initial problem instead of about your non-working solution?

Simpler:

```
call setline('.', substitute(getline('.'), 'A\(foo\)B', 'C\1D', 'g'))
```

Even simpler:

```
s/A\(foo\)B/c\1D/g
```

Comment: Of course it can be useful, but my question is not "how to replace characters in this pattern", but "how can i replace the groups in ANY pattern". So your answer solves the example, but not the question.

Comment: You do that by using groups for everything, what you want to change *and* what you don't want to change: `substitute('foobarbaz', '\(foo\)\(bar\)\(baz\)', '\1café\3', 'g')` that gives you at most 9 "slots" that you can move around freely in the replacement part. But again, your question is very messy: you ask about your failed solution instead of asking about the problem. Please simplify it as much as possible and make sure you describe the initial problem.

Comment: Quotation from myself: "One solution is to use submatches for the 'inner words' ..., but it decreasing the number of useful submatches." To use those just for 'anchoring' is not a good method.

Comment: Again, your "solution" is a red herring: ask about your problem.